# Global call to the notification function in VUEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to make a global function with message passing based on the vue-notification component

I can call a simple alert from the desired component

notification.js

```
export function notifAlert(message)  {
    alert(message)
}
```

in text.vue page

```
import { notifAlert } from '@/utils/notification'
export default { 
...
    methods: {
        onButtonClick() {
            notifAlert('1123');
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out how to connect vue-notification to also call them as a simple message

notification.js

```
import VueNotifications from "vue-notifications";

export function notifAlert(messageText)  {
    notifications: {
        showSuccessMsg(): {
            type: VueNotifications.types.success,
            title: "Success",
            message: messageText
        },
        showInfoMsg: { ... },
        showWarnMsg: { ... },
        showErrorMsg: { ... },
    }
}
```

And how do I call showSuccessMsg (text) and others in methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to accomplish this with `mixins` ..

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/oze4/vue-mixin-notifications-poc/tree/master/?fontsize=14

Comment: Great, that's what I need, but `type: VueNotifications.types.success,` not need use in AlertMixin.js?

Comment: I used a separate plugin called mini-toastr (it was in the vue-notifications documentation on GitHub).  Give that one a try, see if it works. Thanks!!

Comment: i have this error `TypeError: this.showSuccessMsg is not a function` on page vue

Comment: Is this link not working for you? I would need to see the code you are writing, first.. Make sure to mark answer as accepted and we can chat outside of this thread as it seems you are getting a new error.. https://codesandbox.io/s/github/oze4/vue-mixin-notifications-poc/tree/master/?fontsize=14